# Storing data in isolated storage

Tags: c#

How can I store a variable in [isolated storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx) and retrieve it later in a C# console application?

I know how to store data in files in isolated storage: first I need to get isolated store and then I need to create a directory and then a file under that directory and perform read/write operations on that file. I can do this with stream reader and writer

```
var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

IsolatedStorageFileStream rootFile = store.CreateFile("hello.txt");

store.CreateDirectory("Conditions");
```

How can I do the same by just using variables, with no files?

Comment: What do you mean by "Isolated Storage"?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is only available for silverlight.

Similar mechanism is [there](http://ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings) for Metro Apps.

But for normal desktop Applications similar class is not present.

If i have to approach, i will create similar class, MyLocalStorageSettings, and maintain a Dictionary inside it.

To any modification in dictionary i will save to disk (using IsolatedStorageFile). This dictionary should be loaded either at the time application is loaded, or at the first access to this class.

I have utilized similar approach for storing complex settings in [Metro Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229512), where existing infrastructure is not sufficient.

Comment: @tilakoh the approach u r telling me to create a class and then maintain a dictionary there...it will complicate my project....so what i did, i went with the same approach, i'm maintaining a file in isolated storage memory and storing my data in that file..

Comment: well, data is anyway maintained in file. It is an abstraction so that the Settings can be used in dictionary like syntax. If you are storing only 1 type of data, that's fine. But if multiple data are required  to be loaded/saved from multiple code points, it generally make sense to maintain a dictionary like collection

Comment: yep...correct, but i only have to store date variable in that file so my approach worked for me..thanks anyways..i'll keep this in mind for multiple data..